# Store mailer class and method after email sent in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm working on creating a database-backed email auditing system so I can keep track of email messages. The tricky part is I would love to be able to organize these by the mailer classes and also be able to store the name of the mailer method.

It's not difficult to create a mailer interceptor or observer to gather the data from the `Mail::Message` instance, but I'm curious if there's a way to capture the class and method name that created the instance of that message.

I would prefer not to use callbacks if at all possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you need just to access the ApplicationMailer class the created the message, you could use `Mail::Message#delivery_handler`, plain and simple. Accessing the actual method name is non trivial, and your answer below is a genius solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to illuminate a simpler answer that is hinted at by Mark Murphy's first comment, I went with a very simple approach like this:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@theapp.com"
  after_action :log_email

  private
  def log_email
    mailer_class = self.class.to_s
    mailer_action = self.action_name
    EmailLog.log("#{mailer_class}##{mailer_action}", message)
  end
end
```

With a simple model EmailLog to save the record

```
class EmailLog < ApplicationRecord

  def self.log(email_type, message)
    EmailLog.create(
      email_type: email_type,
      from: self.comma_separated(message.from),
      to: self.comma_separated(message.to),
      cc: self.comma_separated(message.cc),
      subject: message.subject,
      body: message.body)
  end

  private
  def self.comma_separated(arr)
    if !arr.nil? && !arr.empty?
      arr.join(",")
    else
      ""
    end
  end

end
```

If all of your mailers derive from ApplicationMailer, then you're all set.

Comment: This is certainly the best answer in this day and age

Comment: This will log not only the emails that were sent, but also those that were just created (without calling #deliver or #deliver_now). That's why you need observer, which will be called after (and only if) an email was sent.

I'm surprised that this answer is 6 years old and nobody noticed this.

Answer (score 15):

Here's what I ended up going with... I would love some feedback about the pros and cons of doing it this way. Feels kind of ugly to me but it was easy. Basically, I included the ability to use callbacks in my mailer, attaching the class and method name metadata to the `Mail::Message` object so that it would be accessible in my observer. I attached it by setting instance variables on the `Mail::Message` object, and then sending `attr_reader` to the `Mail::Message` class, allowing me to call `mail.mailer_klass` and `mail.mailer_action`.

I did it this way because I wanted to record the `Mail::Message` object after it had been delivered so I could get the exact date it had been sent and know that the logged email should have successfully sent.

The mailer:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@theapp.com"

  include AbstractController::Callbacks

  # Where I attach the class and method
  after_action :attach_metadata

  def welcome_note(user)
    @user = user

    mail(subject: "Thanks for signing up!", to: @user.email)
  end

  private

    def attach_metadata
      mailer_klass = self.class.to_s
      mailer_action = self.action_name

      self.message.instance_variable_set(:@mailer_klass, mailer_klass)
      self.message.instance_variable_set(:@mailer_action, mailer_action)

      self.message.class.send(:attr_reader, :mailer_klass)
      self.message.class.send(:attr_reader, :mailer_action)
    end
end
```

The observer:

```
class MailAuditor

  def self.delivered_email(mail)
    if mail.multipart?
      body = mail.html_part.decoded
    else
      body = mail.body.raw_source
    end

    Email.create!(
      sender: mail.from,
      recipient: mail.to,
      bcc: mail.bcc,
      cc: mail.cc,
      subject: mail.subject,
      body: body,
      mailer_klass: mail.mailer_klass,
      mailer_action: mail.mailer_action,
      sent_at: mail.date
    )
  end
end
```

config/initializers/mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(MailAuditor)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I would probably just make a model concern which you would then include in your mailer. The model concern would add an after_action which would do essentially what your observer does. The upside to doing it this way is that you would be in the context of your mailer instance and wouldn't need the attach_metadata method anymore.

Comment: You could also use ActiveSupport::Notifications. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#deliver-action-mailer

Basically you would create an initializer which would subscribe to `deliver.action_mailer` and from there you'll have access to everything you need I think, except maybe for the action name...

Comment: This is a genius level answer. Works flawlessly using the convenience of observer methods, that allow to access the actual data being sent (like the Message-ID).

Comment: Is there a way to get the argments passed to the mailer action? I see they are available to the "process.action_mailer" instrumention, but don't seem to be available to the interceptors?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what you're asking here ... you want to track when the Mailer is used or where it's used from?

If it's the former, you could hook into method calls with something like: https://gist.github.com/ridiculous/783cf3686c51341ba32f

If it's the latter, then the only way I can think of is using `__callee__` to get that info.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I will experiment with this. To further clarify, I want to build a mechanism that tracks whenever our Rails app sends an email. It would record basic info, and then ideally the specific mailer class and mailer action. So the record would look like: `#<Email mailer_class: "UserMailer", mailer_action: "welcome_note", to: "user@example.com", from: "noreply@app.com", sent_at: Fri, 16 Jan 2015 10:27:18 -0800>`

Comment: Hey Jared, I like you're solution.  But like you said, it is a bit ugly. There are a few things I would do to clean it up:

1. I'm all about extending classes to better suit your application. So I would just extend `Mail::Message` in an initializer with `module MailMessageExtensions; attr_accessor :mailer_klass, :mailer_action end`
2. In the `.delivered_email` method, the part about `if mail.multipart?` should be moved to it's own method. Whenever you're tempted to add an empty line between code blocks it's a good indication there is another method there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `process_action` [callback](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks.html#method-i-process_action) (why not?) to intercept mailer arguments, eg.:

```
class BaseMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  private

  # see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks.html#method-i-process_action
  def process_action(action_name, *action_args)
    super

    track_email_status(action_name, action_args)
  end

  # move these methods to the concern, copied here for the sake of simplicity!
  def track_email_status(action_name, action_args)
    email_status = EmailStatus.create!(
      user: (action_args.first if action_args.first.is_a?(User)),
      email: message.to.first,
      mailer_kind: "#{self.class.name}##{action_name}",
      mailer_args: tracked_mailer_args(action_name, action_args)
    )

    message.instance_variable_set(:@email_status, email_status)
  end

  def tracked_mailer_args(action_name, action_args)
    args_map = method(action_name).parameters.map(&:second).zip(action_args).to_h
    args_map = self.class.parameter_filter.filter(args_map)
    simplify_tracked_arg(args_map.values)
  end

  def simplify_tracked_arg(argument)
    case argument
    when Hash then argument.transform_values { |v| simplify_tracked_arg(v) }
    when Array then argument.map { |arg| simplify_tracked_arg(arg) }
    when ActiveRecord::Base then "#{argument.class.name}##{argument.id}"
    else argument
    end
  end

  def self.parameter_filter
    @parameter_filter ||= ActionDispatch::Http::ParameterFilter.new(Rails.application.config.filter_parameters)
  end
end
```

This way you can track mailer headers/class/action_name/arguments and build sophisticated emails tracking backend. You can also use an Observer to track when email was sent:

```
class EmailStatusObserver

  def self.delivered_email(mail)
    mail.instance_variable_get(:@email_status)&.touch(:sent_at)
  end

end

# config/initializers/email_status_observer.rb
ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(EmailStatusObserver)
```

RSpec test:

```
describe BaseMailer do
  context 'track email status' do
    let(:school) { create(:school) }
    let(:teacher) { create(:teacher, school: school) }
    let(:password) { 'May the Force be with you' }
    let(:current_time) { Time.current.change(usec: 0) }

    around { |example| travel_to(current_time, &example) }

    class TestBaseMailer < BaseMailer
      def test_email(user, password)
        mail to: user.email, body: password
      end
    end

    subject { TestBaseMailer.test_email(teacher, password) }

    it 'creates EmailStatus with tracking data' do
      expect { subject.deliver_now }.to change { EmailStatus.count }.by(1)

      email_status = EmailStatus.last
      expect(email_status.user_id).to eq(teacher.id)
      expect(email_status.email).to eq(teacher.email)
      expect(email_status.sent_at).to eq(current_time)
      expect(email_status.status).to eq(:sent)
      expect(email_status.mailer_kind).to eq('TestBaseMailer#test_email')
      expect(email_status.mailer_args).to eq(["Teacher##{teacher.id}", '[FILTERED]'])
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: spot on this, thanks!

Comment: I wonder, does the send_status work with `deliver_later`

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use an `alias_method_chain` type approach - similar to Ryan's approach, but without using `eval`.

https://gist.github.com/kenmazaika/cd80b0379655d39690d8

Never been a big fan of observers.